# Wsl 2 - when docker build - windows host dns lost

Tags: docker, networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

everytime I'm building a docker image using docker build
I'm losing dns on windows host (dns still working on wsl)
But on windows chrome/edge/firefox, I can still do search on google.com
but every other websites doesn't respond(saying the site cannot respond, check your connection, ...).

After between 5 or 10 minutes after docker build finished, the dns recovers.

Does someone has a solution to avoid this ?

I'm using Windows 11 22H2 (22621.2283) but it was happening as well with windows 10.
I'm using wsl 2 with docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:32:12 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:32:12 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.24
  GitCommit:        61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.9
  GitCommit:        v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Docker info

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.12.2
    Path:     /home/wsl/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 79
  Running: 4
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 75
 Images: 206
 Server Version: 24.0.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc version: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 9.717GiB
 Name: ZSOPL-PF35KQ2R
 ID: GRCU:DKQ7:GOMF:BMLR:ZCDJ:CLBR:4I7V:LPPW:76DJ:SHVP:BT33:YSNZ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/go/attack-surface/
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
```

My Wsl config /etc/resolv.conf

<strike>nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4</strike>

Updated with [gregHNZ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218539/wsl-2-when-docker-build-windows-host-dns-lost?noredirect=1#comment136131207_77218539) suggestion

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.21.128.1
```

Wsl config /etc/docker/daemon.json
Updated with @gregHNZ suggestion (removed dns part too)

```json
{
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
  ],
  "tls": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

%UserProfile.wslconfig

```
[wsl2]
memory=10GB
swap=0
guiApplications=false
```

I don't have any VPN

Things I tried:

- I tried to upgrade my Wifi drivers
- I tried restarting my wifi adapter
- I tried [gregHNZ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218539/wsl-2-when-docker-build-windows-host-dns-lost?noredirect=1#comment136131207_77218539) suggestion to remove generateResolvConf = false from /etc/wsl.conf (of course restarting wsl) without any success. I also removed dns section of the /etc/docker/daemon.json file without any success too.
- I followed [second gregHNZ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218539/wsl-2-when-docker-build-windows-host-dns-lost?noredirect=1#comment136143116_77218539) suggestion and used dnsTunneling=true, useWindowsDnsCache=true on .wslconfig.  I even activated systemd just in case. But still same result. I think it is related to windows network driver.

Comment: If you've got `generateResolvConf = false` in your `/etc/wsl.conf` it might be worth experimenting with removing that and letting WSL inherit the host nameserver.  If you're in an enterprise environment, it's possible that there's group policy preventing the use of those nameservers.  Do you do any other internet heavy stuff from WSL? Might be worth trying to trigger it with something else like `curl` or `wget` to pin down whether it's docker itself, or network.

Comment: thanks @GregHNZ for the suggestion, I tried it but I still have the same issue unfortunately. I updated by post accordingly

Comment: FWIW, My docker info is virtually the same as yours - I have a slightly older Ubuntu (22.04.2 LTS) but otherwise identical. My docker builds are relatively trivial, and we only push to AWS ECR.  This page has some _experimental_ settings that look relevant to DNS (and was written relatively recenty): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I tried to use these options dnsTunneling=true, useWindowsDnsCache=true.  I even activated systemd just in case. But still same result. I think it is related to windows network driver